# Powershell: string manipulations

Tags: string, powershell, wmi

I'll explain what i want by example, not sure how to explain it another way.

Heres the code im using :

```
Get-WmiObject win32_share | select name, path
```

an example entry is from the above is:

name       path
ADMIN$     C:\windows
C$         C:\

I want to put all names and paths into one variable.  I want the string to look something like:

> "Name: admin, path: C:\windows ; Name: c$, path: C:\ ; ect ect.."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
[string]::Join("; ", (Get-WmiObject win32_share | % { [string]::Format("Name: {0}, Path: {1}", $_.Name, $_.Path)}))
```

Comment: Good answer, though Powershell way would be: `(Get-WmiObject win32_share |%{ "Name: {0}, Path: {1}" -f $_.Name,$_.Path }) -join "; "`

Comment: thanks. it works great.  What is this? is it a regular expression?

Answer (score 3):

Slight modification in approach from @SINTER's answer and using more POSH syntax:

```
$out="";Get-WmiObject win32_share | %{ $out+="Name: {0}, Path: {1}; " -f $_.Name, $_.Path}
```

Comment: It's all Posh syntax imho, just one way is confined to cmdlets only, another utilizes .NET classes directly.

Comment: @AndyArismendi - In my opinion, when Powershell has "-join" and "-f", you should be using that over the BCL which achieves the same. Definitely, anything using the former is more POSH.